# My code is not working. How can I add after and before elements on a clipped div?

Tags: html, css, shadow, dropshadow

This is my code in which I want to develop a navigation bar similar to the attached image. For shadow I searched and found that on wrapping the parent div we can give shadow using **dropshadow()** but now I want to give solid 2px border for this, I tried ::before but that didn't work. I am unable to understand the reason.

```css
.mybar{
   
    background-color: black;
    width: 90%;
    height: 40px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0%,95% 100%,5% 100%);
    padding: 0px;
  
    
}
.forshadow{filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.45rem #ac04cb);}

.mybar::before{
    content: " ";
    background-color:#d673ff ;
    width:93%;
    height: 43px;
}
```

```html
<div class="forshadow">
                  
      <div class="mybar">
                            
      </div>
                  
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use an `svg` for this. Because of the clip-path property, the borders will be cut out of the viewport.

There are three solutions that come to my mind:

1. You could use an svg
2. Draw a rectangle with a clip-path and
   then have two pseudo-elements on the left and right side that will be drawn as triangles (transparent with a border)
3. Use an image instead (I suggest the .gif format, since its all the same color)

```css
.forshadow {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.45rem #ac04cb);
  width: 800px; /* the container width - adjust */
  height: 50px; /* the container height - adjust */
}

.mybar {
  width: 100%; /* 100% of the container - will always adapt to the container */
  height: 100%; /* 100% of the container - will always adapt to the container */
  fill: #000000; /* background */
  stroke: hotpink; /* border color */
  stroke-width: 2; /* border size */
}
```

```html
<div class="forshadow">
  <svg class="mybar" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="0,0 100,0 95,50 5,50" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I suggest the svg-solution. It is made to be scaleable. You can just edit the parameters and play around with it.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

**EDIT:**

You can save the svg as a file (.svg). And then add it as a `background-image` to the container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .navbar {
     filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.45rem #ac04cb);
     width: 800px; /* the container width - adjust */
     height: 50px; /* the container height - adjust */
        color: white;
     background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIiB2aWV3Ym94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDUwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwIiBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJub25lIj4KCTxwb2x5Z29uIGNsYXNzPSJteWJhciIgcG9pbnRzPSIwLDAgMTAwLDAgOTUsNTAgNSw1MCIgdmVjdG9yLWVmZmVjdD0ibm9uLXNjYWxpbmctc3Ryb2tlIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==");
     /* alternative, non-base-64: background-image: url("your-file.svg");*/
     background-size: 100% 100%;
   }

      /* this will style the <polygon> element inside the svg */
   .mybar {
     width: 100%; /* 100% of the container - will always adapt to the container */
     height: 100%; /* 100% of the container - will always adapt to the container */
     fill: #000000; /* background */
     stroke: hotpink; /* border color */
     stroke-width: 2; /* border size */
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar">
      <div>The svg is just a background image - we can write on it.</div>
    </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

The svg-file that I have used and decoded:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 100 50" width="100" height="50" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon class="mybar" points="0,0 100,0 95,50 5,50" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: that's perfect.I never used svg before. :)

Comment: but the problem is that svg is not behaving like a div then how can i add ul li inside the polygon...? little confuse here

Comment: Thank you for helping.I already used polygon as absolute element and z-index attribute thats works perfectly i completed my work thanks alot once again 

Comment: @WaniaKanwal Ok great. Glad I could help. So did it actually work with clip-path? Or how did you solve it finally? Did not understand what you meant exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `border: 2px solid red` to the div where you want a border.

```css
.mybar{
    background-color: black;
    width: 90%;
    height: 40px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0%,95% 100%,5% 100%);
    padding: 0px; 
}

.forshadow {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.45rem #ac04cb);
}
```

```html
<div class="forshadow">
                  
      <div style="border: 2px solid red" class="mybar"></div>
                  
</div>
```

Does the solution look like you imagined?
I used red color for the border. You can change that, of course.

Comment: Probably not, since it does not cover all edges. And this is the tricky part as the clip-path cut the edges out of the viewport.

Comment: @F.Müller "But now I want to give it a fixed 2px border", he wrote in his question ... no more ...

Comment: He has edited his question. Before, he wrote he wants it to be as in the screenshot below. And you can see that it has a border on both left- and right side. Looks weird without.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen "from now" i meant after adding shadow to the div.

Comment: yes @F. Müller i want the border all around the clipped div just like the image.Thanks for helping both of you :)

Comment: @WaniaKanwal And what about the svg solution?